# How to change navbar functionality after login or logout CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to change navbar functionality so after the user logged in, the buttons of  "register" and "login" will replaced by single button of "logout"...
I tried in this way but didn't succeed.

C:\xampp\htdocs\jobfinds\src\Template\Element\menu.ctp

```
    <div class="col_12 column"> 
        <ul class="menu">           
               <li> Home</li>   
            <?php if(isset($user['id'])): ?>
               <li>Logout</li>              
            <?php else: ?>          
               <li>Login</li>   
               <li> Register</li>           
            <?php endif ; ?>
        </ul>       
    </div>
```

I tried to pass $user to view in the login method by using

```
$this->set('user',$user);
```

but the menu.ctp didn't recognize it...
so how can I actually make it work?

Comment: try to store data in $_SESSION and then test

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is to check in your controller if `$this->Auth->user()` does not return null, and simply set any variable you want. Additionally, if you want to use it in element, you must make sure that this variable is correctly set in all actions. So best place will be `beforeRender()` action in your AppController. Here is how it could look like:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event){

    /* --- */

    if (is_object($this->Auth)) {
        if ($this->Auth->user() !== null) {
            $this->set("userIsLoggedIn", true);
        } else {
            $this->set("userIsLoggedIn", false);
        }
    }

    /* --- */

}
```

And in your element:

```
<?php if(isset($userIsLoggedIn) && $userIsLoggedIn): ?>
    <span>User is logged in</span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span>User is NOT logged in</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It works perfectly but when i'm pressing on one of the navigation arrows on the left bottom of the debugkit it displays me this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function user() on boolean in...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function user() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobfinds\src\Controller\AppController.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\jobfinds\src\Controller\ErrorController.php(54): App\Controller\AppController->beforeRender(Object(Cake\Event\Event))

Comment: In addition i'm dealing with a new problem wich is that i'm not able to add a new job even thogh all seems to be ok. the inputs passes to url but the saving action is not happening and no flash for succeed or failur.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your first comment - please look again at controller code.

Comment: Ok with this updated answer it works without no errors at all.